# How to get list of *.jpg files on server?

Tags: android

I'm trying to find simplest solution to make app where I can download all the images from the specifed, hardcoded directory.

So far, my idea is to get list of all .jpg images (since it will be the only image format in this directory) and put it in places on ViewPager so each image will be on seperate page.

Anyone has nice snippet or friendly library to use to make it happen?

Comment: there is alot of image libabries like picasso or universal image loader

Comment: For downloading a list of specific files on server?

Comment: yes, download, set in ImageView, different cache mechanisms (memory, files, expiry followup...) and much more, just google it

Comment: those libs never mention about bulk image download - only for single images. Could You be more specific?

Comment: why do you want bulk download? you want each image on separate page, or using ViewPager so on next view (slide) load the next image, why download 1000 image when the user may slide 2 or 3 times?!

Comment: I need to download between 5 to 15 images and since I don't exactly know how much there will be uploaded I wanted to make sure that I download all of them. It will be used with ViewPager. I have done it with JSON (specifed images addresses) so it works, but I need something to get those images names to ArrayList.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a txt file on the server in which the URLs of all images will be kept; then program your app to download this file first; then use input stream to read the URLs from the file and create a loop to download all urls until they finish, by checking if the input is null.

On server side either add the urls manually to the file or write a JavaScript to automatically write the URLs when uploading the image.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, hence I asked it months ago :) But tell me: how did You found it since it should be lost in in search results?